# Clicking doesn't autocomplete when @username in a comment is not in the beginning

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, notifications

Using IE8.

Clicking the suggestion box with @user_names doesn't work when the @user_name is not going to be the first token in the comment (which may happen when I want to notify a user while talking to another user or to general public ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330539/how-to-get-and-set-a-vb6-property-with-parameter-from-c#comment13320992_10330539))).

When I click the suggestion box, it goes bold, but the name is not inserted in the comment, and a js error occurs:

> **'name' is `null` or not an object**
>   Line: 159
>   Character: 142
>   Code: 0
>   URI: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/full.js?v=d90e8064a7a4

Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> in this situation works as expected. Only clicking does not work.

Comment: Could you briefly explain *why* you **need** to use IE8?  This might deter people from posting comments such as - `"Upgrade to a better more current browser!"` ;)

Comment: @Lix I was willing to upgrade and I gave IE9 a go. They completely broke the search box by merging it with the address bar. I'm using the search box quite often and I have many search providers installed, and the way it works in IE9 makes me suffer every time I try to use it. I've looked online for any hotkeys/tips on using the new merged bar, it wasn't any good either. So I rolled back to IE8. I'm not exactly happy with that situation.

Comment: It's still too early to think about dropping IE8 on a wide scale yet... even I am still supporting it in my designs.

Comment: FWIW, this (age old) IE issue is still present in IE9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working with text boxes in response to click events is always a challenge in IE. But at least the fix for this (next build, as alawys) also made the click behavior more consistent with the TAB behavior in other browsers.

Comment: A little glitch is found in the fix. Now, when I click, the name goes bold and inserts into the textbox, but the textbox loses its focus. So when I click and then press space, the page is scrolled one screen down because the space goes to the page, not the textbox.